# grep or find on Android

Tags: c, linux, android-ndk

These are not installed on Android 4.2.1 by default, so is it possible to cross-compile the source for e.g. [GNU](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grep/) `grep` or `find` and have it run on Android?  ( Preferably **without having to root** the device or installing some app off [PLAY](https://play.google.com/store) e.g. busybox.) Are there any missing dependencies that will prevent this? I am developing on Ubuntu 10.0.04

Comment: the best answer is that you should put framaroot on your android. Then any root action would be fine @cyberSecurity

Answer (score 0):

Strange. I have them on `/system/xbin/*`. Maybe more luck with busybox. `busybox find` `busybox grep` Not sure if busybox is installed by default on Android 4.2 tho, but it's a pretty common binary.

Comment: i also use busybox for that 'grep' stuff... but seems if i search through all subdirectories from / -> root location, it just stop like a 'hang'. Have you been experiencing like this @ablm?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer because I haven't tried building `grep` or `find`. However, in general it is quite possible to build GNU utilities for Android. To do this, the best option is:

1. Download the Android native development kit
2. Build an Android [standalone toolchain by referring to `docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html` in the NDK](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html)
3. Simply build the relevant GNU utility using the normal `./configure && make` mechanism.

You'll then need to copy the resulting binaries onto your Android device, which you can do using `adb push`. You may need to arrange to put them into `/data/` somewhere because `/mnt/sdcard` is often marked non-executable.

### Missing dependencies

The main problem you'll find during the actual builds is that Android does not use the standard GNU `libc` (glibc). Instead, it uses its own, called Bionic. This does miss certain important APIs - for example, wide character string support.

I've found for some GNU utilities this is OK and they can be compiled with minimal source code changes.

However, if you run into trouble, you're probably better off using other versions of these utilities which are typically designed for more flexibility in terms of the underlying libc. Specifically, the previous advice about using `busybox` is excellent. If you don't wish to install it from the Android market, you can find the source code [here](http://code.google.com/p/busybox-android/).